# [AOSP]Update preloaded classes list

Tags: android-source, android.mk

I created a java library that containing 3 classes,I added these class names in "/frameworks/base/config/preloaded-classes" for preloading. 
But in startup logcat showing following error.

```
W/Zygote: Class not found for preloading: com.example.my.lib.preloadlibshared.CalcUtil
W/Zygote: Class not found for preloading: com.example.my.lib.preloadlibshared.CompareUtil
W/Zygote: Class not found for preloading: com.example.my.lib.preloadlibshared.DrawUtil
```

My intention is to preload classes in my jar file.

Any clues on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a `Android.mk` for jar library to build your library to a module.
2. Add your library module to `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS`, and the value will be wrote into `init.rc`.
3. Add your library module to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`.
4. Add your defined class to `build/core/tasks/check_boot_jars/package_whitelist.txt` to avoid the system check to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS` in your *.mk